# Solver software for finding ALL solutions to a pure integer MIP

Tags: c++, c, integer, solver

I have a set of problems (sets of equations and inequalities) for which I know that all variables have to be integers, and have finitely many solutions. I know that if I take any random objective function and let an lp or mip solver onto it, it finds **a** solution, however I want **all** solutions to the problem, and of course, as efficiently as possible. I don't really care about optimizing anything, but apparently most of the software that deals with it does. Is there any solver that can do that? If so, which one is the best/simplest one, or which one would you recommend? At best one that can be used as a C/C++ library.

Comment: http://www.or-exchange.com/questions/26/open-sourcefree-mip-solver?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a nice [blog post](http://orinanobworld.blogspot.com/2012/04/k-best-solutions.html) by Paul Rubin on how to find `K` best solutions, which can be easily generalized to get all the solutions. As Ali suggested one of the approaches is to use a solution pool. Two other approaches are:

1. Use an incumbent callback to track and reject solutions.
2. Use an incumbent callback with solution injection.

See the [blog post](http://orinanobworld.blogspot.com/2012/04/k-best-solutions.html) for details.

Comment: Yep, that's what I imagined, that you'd have to do it manually. I guess pretty much everyone who uses solvers is only interested on one optimal solution. But this method is much better than what I had thought, which was to try exhaust solutions via the different objective functions. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

[IBM ILOG CPLEX](http://www.ibm.com/software/integration/optimization/cplex-optimizer/) has a [solution pool](http://www.decf.berkeley.edu/help/apps/ampl/cplex-doc/relnotescplex/relnotescplex19.html) feature and it's free for academic purposes.

I guess you can probably get all solution if you set the maximum pool size sufficiently large. I don't know for sure, never tried.

Comment: It's a good start, thanks. I think the blog post vitaut mentions is the way to go if you want to be sure you have all solutions, however.

Comment: @Goens Yes, I didn't know about that blog post.